# Is subclassing application the only way to implement static helper methods in Android?

Tags: android, subclass

I want to have a helper classes such as Convert or Utils in my android app. Typical issue I have is:

```
public class Convert {

    private Convert() {
        // I can't be instantiated
    }

    public static int pxToDp(float pixels) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, pixels, displayMetrics);
    }
}
```

The above fails of course because Convert has no idea what getResources() is. 
So that leaves me two options:

1. pass a context each time I want to use a helper method, which is rubbish
2. subclass Application, modify my manifest, then create a reference, like this:

   ```
   public class App extends Application {

       private static Context mContext;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           mContext = this;
       }

       public static Context getContext() {
           return mContext;
       }
   }
   ```

then do `App.getContext()` everywhere I need it.

Question: this can't be right, what's the elegant way to proceed?

Comment: I wish I could +1 this more than once - I personally went with the "passing Context as an argument" and felt terrible about it...

Comment: What's wrong with subclassing Application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you subllcass Application that will obviously work, but you may end up with an enormous, horrible class that does a whole bunch of stuff that's unrelated - walking roughshod over the Single Responsibility Principle.

Yes it's a bit messy and annoying passing a Context into a utility class, but it means you can create classes for each type of utility (e.g. StringUtils, or whatever) and at least keep the responsibilities separate.

I'd advise against using App.getContext everywhere as it means all your utility classes will be dependent on App, which makes it hard to reuse them. If you pass in a context, you can more easily reuse some of the utility classes in other apps.

So I'd say use separate classes, and pass that Context in to the methods. It's a little ugly, but in my opinion much less ugly than the alternatives.

Comment: This is correct.  If you've programmed in Android much, you'll notice that's exactly how the API does it.

The only concern with this is the extra overhead when calling your utility class method.  If your utility class need not be static, you can simply create a member field that contains a context passed on instantiation. This would also work and prevent the need to pass one every time.  The caveat here is, your utility class methods can no longer be declared static if it depends on the class being instantiated.

Comment: And I'm sure you don't want a bunch of utility classes clutting up your precious memory.  So, you could make it a singleton.  Doing that, however, would mean it will only work with one context at a time.  This may be fine, but ideally, a utility class is meant to be called from any context.

Answer (score 0):

> *pass a context each time I want to use a helper method, which is rubbish*

That sounds like OOP religion to me.  I would actually pass in the `DisplayMetrics`, because that's what the function really needs to calculate its answer.